# Python, "subprocess.check_ouput()" hangs while installing rpm

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to install .rpm through subprocess.check_ouput()
i.e.

```
buff=subprocess.check_output(["rpm","-ivh","Package_Name"])
```

**Even though package is successfully installed, python script is stuck at this instruction (not executing below instructions.)**

Please note that other "rpm" operation is working properly with subprocess.check_output()

After including **shell=True**,
i.e.

```
buff=subprocess.check_output(["rpm","-ivh","Package_Name"],shell=True)
```

Package is not getting installed and It is throwing error at this instruction,
Error : rpm Usage

Can anyone help?

Comment: Its lat, but did you have any luck with this?